# Limit input to show only thousans in HTML or JS

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have an input filed where the user can enter some numbers. I want to limit the user to enter only thousands.

[image: please see image].

on the image, the user can enter other numbers even if the step is 1000.

Comment: Just to be clear, if the input is empty and the user enters "2", do you want it to immediately show "2000"?

Comment: with step at 1000, user can still enter "11111" as in your example, but when leaving the input, you'll notice it's bordered in red and shows a notice to the user on hover. So it should work fine

Comment: @Archer I want when user enter 2333 to become 2000.

Comment: So you only want it to update when they leave the input?

Comment: yes. when they leave input I want it to change value to thousands. If user leaves an input with 33333 I want it to become 30000

Answer (score 1):

onblur is executed when you lose the focus, so try this :

```js
function autoThousand(){
  var input = document.getElementById('thousand');
  if (input.value%1000 !== 0 ){
    input.value-=input.value%1000;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="thousand" onblur="autoThousand();" step="1000">
```

Answer (score 0):

use this,

if you still want to make the field number field set the type="number" , step="1000", min="1000" max="any value of your choice"

```
<input type="text" name="quantity" id="num" onchange="checkInput()">
<script>
function checkInput(){
get_num = new Number(document.getElementById('num').value)
if(get_num < 1000){
document.getElementById('num').value =  ""
alert("You must enter number in thousands")
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will round all number inputs to multiples of their step value, when they lose focus. It uses traditional rounding, where it rounds 1499 down to 1000 and 1500 up to 2000.  (You can remove the commented line of code to always round down.)

This is one of those *"add it and forget it"* bits of code, where you just need to add inputs of type number, with a limit, and it will automatically round them all for you.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("input[type=number][limit]").forEach(function(input) {
  input.addEventListener("change", function() {
    var value = parseInt(this.value, 10);
    var limit = parseInt(this.getAttribute("limit"), 10);
    value = value + (limit / 2); // remove this to always round down
    this.value = value - (value % limit);
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="number" limit="1000" />(multiples of 1000)<br />
<input type="number" limit="100" />(multiples of 100)<br />
<input type="number" limit="500" />(multiples of 500)<br />
```

Answer (score -1):

Set 'max', 'min' and 'step' value.

```
  <input type="number" name="points" step="1000" max="100000" min="1000">
```